# Python Text file layouts

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I want to be able to read and write on a text file in a good well set layout.

Here is what I have so far to read and write on files. Very basic but does the job perfectly.

Writing files:

```
def writefile():
    file = open("database.txt","w") 
    file.write("Testing.. Testing.. 123.") 
    file.close()
    print("Written on file [database.txt] successful")
```

Reading files:

```
def readfile():
    file = open("database.txt","r") 
    print(file.read())
    file.close()
```

However, I need it so that I can handle an ID and a TEAMNAME properly in one file.
I need it in this layout or similar.

This layout in a textfile called database.txt

```
TEAMNAME: MISFITS, ID: 250
TEAMNAME: BLUES, ID: 170
TEAMNAME: EAZY, ID: 154
TEAMNAME: SUPER, ID: 124
```

The program must be able to write in this layout and read in this layout.

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is either a simple .ini file or a proper database file.

A .ini file can look like this:

```
[Team1]
name=x
foo=1
bar=2

[Team2]
...
```

.ini files can be read in Python with the configparser module:

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.sections()
[]
>>> config.read('example.ini')
['example.ini']
>>> config.sections()
['bitbucket.org', 'topsecret.server.com']
>>> 'bitbucket.org' in config
True
>>> 'bytebong.com' in config
False
>>> config['bitbucket.org']['User']
'hg'
>>> config['DEFAULT']['Compression']
'yes'
>>> topsecret = config['topsecret.server.com']
>>> topsecret['ForwardX11']
'no'
>>> topsecret['Port']
'50022'
>>> for key in config['bitbucket.org']: print(key)
...
```

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

More information on database files and how to use them in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

To read in the layout you have posted, you can read the file line by line, and then split each line at the comma. This information can then be stored in a dictionary.

```
def readfile():
    datalist = []       #create a list to store the dictionaries in

    file = open('database.txt', 'r')
    lines = file.read().split('\n')      #this creates a list containing each line

    for entry in lines:             #scan over all of the lines
        parts = entry.split(',')    #split it at the comma
        dictionary = dict()
        for part in parts:
           dictionary[part.split(':')[0].strip()] = part.split(':')[1].strip()

        datalist.append(dictionary)

    file.close()
    return datalist
```

`datalist` is a list containing dictionaries, which contain the information. It can be used like so:

```
for item in datalist:
    print('Team Name:', item['TEAMNAME'])
    print('Id:', item['ID'])
```

To write back to the file you can use this:

```
def writefile(datalist):
    file = open('database.txt', 'w')
    for entry in datalist:
        output = ''
        for key in entry.keys():
            output += key
            output += ': '
            output += entry[key]
            output += ', '

        file.write(output[:-2] + '\n')      #get rid of the trailing comma
    file.close()
```

You can add new entries to the list like this:

```
data = readfile()     #get the data
data.append({'TEAMNAME': 'COOL', 'ID': '444'})
writefile(data)       #update the file
```